# How to use SVN 1.8 with Eclipse under Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

we just upgrade to SVN 1.8. Unfortunately nobody thought about us Linux folks :( Is there any way to connect Eclipse to an SVN 1.8?

The repo of [Dominik Stadler](https://launchpad.net/~dominik-stadler/) is mentioned a couple of times in terms of upgrading to 1.7 but the 1.8 Folder looks pretty empty. :( 
I found the the source download of the [cli version](http://subversion.apache.org/download/) which works but is of course not integrated in eclipse.
I cannot find a newer Version of SVN Kit or JavaHL though, which are used by subversive and subclipse as a connector. Is there maybe a plugin which uses the cli client? Or is it just waiting for an update? :(

Thx for any clues

*edit*

There is an Alpha Version of SVN Kit available on their site svnkit.com/download.php that supports SVN 1.8. Unfortuntely I cannot install the eclipse file "Cannot find jar file". Anyone? :(

*edit2*

If I drop the SVN Kit Alpha in the "dropins" folder of eclipse, it is listed in my plugin list but how the &#%$ do I use it now? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LET THERE BE LIGHT!

1. Download the [CollabNetSubversion-client rpm](http://www.open.collab.net/files/documents/60/7397/CollabNetSubversion-client-1.8.0-2.x86_64.rpm) in the correct architecture (registration required).
2. Install rpm `sudo apt-get install rpm`
3. Install svn client without deps: `sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps CollabNetSubversion-client-1.8.0-2. x86_64.rpm`
4. Find collabnet installation `` `sudo updatedb `` then `locate *collabnet*` (or use `find` or whatever you like), should be `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/collabnetsvn-config`
5. Get the lib path, should be `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib`
6. Open your eclipse.ini
7. Enter the lib path`-Djava.library.path=/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib` under the `vmargs` line.
8. Install the SVN Plugin Subclipse (this does not seem to work with Subversive)
9. Choose JavHL (JNI) 1.8.0 as your SVN interface
10. CHECK THE #&%$§# PROJECTS OUT AND COMMIT THE $%&#§ OUT OF THEM!