# Install svn kit from updatesite archieve

Tags: eclipse, svnkit

I have updated my svn to 1.8 which unfortunately is not supported by subversive (using the svnkit connector). Since I would like to avoid downgrading, I am trying to install the [alpha](http://www.svnkit.com/download.php) of the svnkit. I download the "Eclipse Update Site Archive" and extract it.

In eclipse I select "add update site"->"local" and navigate to the folder containing `site.xml`. After this Eclipse tells me "could not find file:/path/I/choose/".

How can I install this connector and do I need further steps to use a svn 1.8 working copy with subversive? (Besides selecting the newly installed connector)

Comment: It does not work with Subversive but works with Subclipse. Subclipse 1.10.0 can handle it, but Subversive needs to build their own plugin based on svnkit.

Comment: @atlanto If I am not mistaken subclipse is based on the JavaHL layer. I am not to eager to use that since I am on a linux machine where I have no root access => I would have to build it from source, which takes me a lot of time (as building subversion showed). If you say it does not work with subversive, do you mean it does not work because svnkit does not support svn 1.8 (yet) or because subversive would need an update itself as well as svnkit?

Comment: The eclipse plugin (subversive or subclipse is not the problem I think) but the connector (SVN Kit or JavaHL). The javaHL of Ubuntu is not up2date (works fine with Windows) and I did not find any sources which you could build. The alpha of SVN Kit as you found out, cannot be installed. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543654/how-to-use-svn-1-8-with-eclipse-under-ubuntu

Comment: @Redfox : I missed your question, but I can't flag mine as a dupolicate, because your question does not have an upvoted or accepted awnser yet. For now I work arround it by using svn from the command line...

Answer (score 0):

LET THERE BE LIGHT!

1. Download the [CollabNetSubversion-client rpm](http://www.open.collab.net/files/documents/60/7397/CollabNetSubversion-client-1.8.0-2.x86_64.rpm) in the correct architecture (registration required).
2. Install rpm `sudo apt-get install rpm`
3. Install svn client without deps: `sudo rpm -ivh --nodeps CollabNetSubversion-client-1.8.0-2. x86_64.rpm`
4. Find collabnet installation `` `sudo updatedb `` then `locate *collabnet*` (or use `find` or whatever you like), should be `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/collabnetsvn-config`
5. Get the lib path, should be `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib`
6. Open your eclipse.ini
7. Enter the lib path`-Djava.library.path=/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib` under the `vmargs` line.
8. Install your SVN Plugin of choice (Subclipse or Subversive)
9. Choose JavHL (JNI) 1.8.0 as your SVN interface
10. CHECK THE #&%$§# PROJECTS OUT AND COMMIT THE $%&#§ OUT OF THEM!

Comment: I just see, now you could flag this as a duplicate. That would be the best way I think.

Comment: I just flagged it, now you can flag it too. ( I voted for the awnser under your question. unfortunately it won't take me to far, since I am not admin on that machine, I will check out if I can relocte it though)

Comment: Ask your admin nicely if he could install it for you :) Maybe extracting the rpm works too, you just need the files after all. Can you edit the ```eclipse.ini```? Good luck!

Comment: Since I am writing my thesis, I decided I have more pressing issues like a compiler crash, I will just wait for a new `svnkit` or try `javahl` @home. After all it sucks but is not worth the effort for the remaining month.